# Colorize barcode bitmap by Color

Tags: c#, zxing, zxing.net

I'm generating barcodes using ZXing.NET with this code

```
BarcodeWriter barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat,
    Options = new EncodingOptions
    {
        Width = barCodeWidth,
        Height = barCodeHeight,
        PureBarcode = !GenerateBarCodeWithText
    }
};

Bitmap barCodeBitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(content);
```

So currently each barcode (and with text) is just black. Is there a way I can pass in a `Color` object to colorize the barcode and text red for example? I tried this hacky solution to get the current pixel color, check if it's white and if not, colorize it to the specified font color.

```
for (int x = 0; x < barCodeBitmap.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < barCodeBitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        Color currentColor = barCodeBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        bool isWhite = currentColor == Color.White;

        if (!isWhite) // this pixel should get a new color
        {
            barCodeBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, fontColor); // set a new color
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately each pixel gets colorized..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For colorizing the whole code (including the text) you can use the following snippet:

```
BarcodeWriter barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter
{
   Format = BarcodeFormat,
   Options = new EncodingOptions
   {
      Width = barCodeWidth,
      Height = barCodeHeight,
      PureBarcode = !GenerateBarCodeWithText
   },
   Renderer = new BitmapRenderer
   {
      Foreground = Color.Red
   }
};

Bitmap barCodeBitmap = barcodeWriter.Write(content);
```

If you want different colors for the barcode and the text you have to write your own renderer implementation and use this instead of the BitmapRenderer.
You can take a look at the sources of BitmapRenderer and use it as a template for your own implementation:

https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/lib/renderer/BitmapRenderer.cs

Add a new property "TextColor" for example and use it in the line

```
var brush = new SolidBrush(Foreground);
```

changed to

```
var brush = new SolidBrush(TextColor);
```